# SQL stats for customers that have not ordered a type of product ever

Tags: sql

In a SQL DB I have a table with a list of customer IDs.  I Also have a table of orders with foreign IDs Price, Quantity and type(1 or 0).

I want to know overall for the list of customers the total Price, the total quantity and the count of orders for customers that have only ever ordered type 0.

I was thinkining I need to first get a list of customers that only ever use type 0 first and then get the stats but not sure how to do this easily.

Order table:

```
|OrderNo| CustomerCD| Type|Price|Quantity|
```

list of customers table( subset of all customers):

```
|customer ID|
```

Looking for a simple query that outputs the overall metrics for customers that have never used type 1

Comment: Please share the code you wrote that produced the incorrect output.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and a database tag would help.

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Comment: I was using 2 seperate queries that created a table of unique customers that I then used as a filter.  The first query just creates a list of customers that only ever ordered type 0 using a `group by ID` and then `HAVING Count(*) = Count(case when type = 0 then 1 end)`.  The second query just does simple counts/sums for IDs in that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use window functions:

```
select customercd, sum(quantity),
       sum(case when num_not_type_0 = 0 then 1 else 0 end)
from (select o.*, sum(case when type <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) as num_not_type_0
      from orders o
     ) o
group by customercd;
```

If you just want overall metrics for customers who never ordered type 1, then `not exists` comes to mind:

```
select sum(quantity), count(*), . . .
from orders o
where not exists (select 1 from orders o2 where o2.customercd = o.customercd and o2.type = 1);
```